# get index List<object> that contain a value, C#, Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am starting in C# Linq.  I would like to performance this query.

I Got an List of object  List with several values per object, one of them is a "Text". I would like to seek which object have an especific text them get the index of the Object for the List.

to get index is not completed

```
var List = GetListObject();
var index = unitList.Select(x => x.Text.ToString().Contains("Text"));
```

Comment: Don't use Linq if you want performance. In your case, use a regular `for` loop as suggested in on of the answers.

Comment: I whole-heatedly agree - I can consistently write code faster than Linq. However, there are advantages, namely readability (if used in short chains) and job interviews. It looks like Andres is learning Linq - a skill that could land a sweet job later on.

Answer (score 2):

check this

```
myLİst.Select((v, i) => new {Text = v, Index = i})
    .First(x=> x.Text.ToString().Contains("Text")).Index;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain *index*, I suggest good old `for` loop:

```
  int index = -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; ++i)
    if (List[i].Text.Contains("Text")) {
      index = i;

      break;
    }
```

In case of *Linq*

```
  int index = List
    .Select((v, i) => new {v, i})
    .FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.v.Text.Contains("Text"))
   ?.i ?? -1;
```

In both cases we get `-1` if item with `Text == "Text"` is not found

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enumerable.Range(int, int).

For example: `var zeroIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count - 1).Where(x => list[x] == 0).ToArray()` will give you an array of all indexes of list where the value is equal to zero.

So specific to your question, you can do:

```
int index = Enumerable.Range(0, unitList.Count - 1).Where(x => unitList[x].Text.ToString().Contains("Text")).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will give your the first index or 0 if not found.